# File on master that was supposed to be on dev - Git

Tags: git, github

Like most good git practices, our team does development on a `dev` branch, then merges to the `master` branch once we know the new development is stable.

I messed up by adding a `.readme` file to `master` on Github, and then pushing some new `.py` files on Git to our `dev` branch. This caused `master` to be ahead of `dev` a commit, but also behind `dev` a commit.

We were able to revert and get them matched up, but now I am encountering the same issue. I need to make edits on the `.readme` file, but it is currently only on `master`, and not `dev`. What would be the best way to copy the file to `dev`, make edits, and push back to `master` without causing the same issue that I did before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you work as following:

- Develop on `dev` branch
- Every certain amount of time - merge `dev` to `master`

so `master` is your release branch.

So now that you made changes to `master` - either by mistake or intentionally (hotfix for example) - simply merge back `master` to `develop`

```
git checkout develop
git merge master
```

In your specific scenario you should have no conflicts, and next it you merge `develop` to `master` everything gets aligned.

Comment: Ok cool, so I will until the end of the day when everyone has made changes on `dev`, and once we merge `dev` with `master`, I'll make sure we do it vice-versa as well (merge `master` to `dev`), and then I can make my changes to the `.readme` file in `dev`. Awesome, thank you!